# wtform selectfield validation not to choose the first in the list

Tags: python, flask

I've got two selectfield that the user should select an airport from a list, however I want the first option will be "make your choice" or something like that, and the user won't be able to choose  (like a default choose)

```
AIR_PORTS_LIST = [(0, 'Make Your Choice'), (1, 'praia'), (2, 'abidjan')]

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    airport_src = SelectField('AirPort Source', choices=AIR_PORTS_LIST, validators=[DataRequired()])
    airport_dst = SelectField('AirPort Destination', choices=AIR_PORTS_LIST, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a default SelectField component.

Comment: How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is known as **Placeholder** and yes you can write in html like this:

```
{{ form.airport_src(placeholder='Make Your Choice') }}
{{ form.airport_dst(placeholder='Make Your Choice') }}
```

There is no need to write it in choices.

Comment: it works, but I still want to force the user to choose another option that is not "Make Your Choice"

Comment: use  validators=[DataRequired()] as well in the ClassForm.

Comment: i did that, i edited the ClassForm at the top, and the html file as you adviced, but it still enable to submit this value..